# Calling native dll inside Parallel.For in C# throws System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, multithreading, dll, parallel-processing, thread-safety

I have a C++ dll which does some image processing using OpenCV and Libtiff. It creates a multipage tif file given an input file (proprietary format), one file at a time.

I have a C# class in which I am calling this dll in a loop for all the files that need to be converted. when I call the dll from a normal for loop, it works fine. When I try to call it from a Parallel.For it crashes and throws System.AccessViolationException.

dll code:

```
extern "C"
    {
        __declspec(dllexport)  int _cdecl extractFisAndCreateGeotiff(char* fisFile, char* infoFisFile, char *tifFile, bool allLayers, double latitude, double longitude, double realX, double realY, double heading);
    }

    int extractFisAndCreateGeotiff(char* fisFile, char* infoFisFile, char* geotifFile, bool allLayers, double latitude, double longitude, double heading, double realLength, double realWidth)
    {   
        //GET LCMS SENSOR INFO
        if(!getLCMSInfo(fisFile)) 
            if(!getLCMSInfo(infoFisFile)) 
                return NO_LCMS_INFO;

            vector<Mat> fisData = extractFisData(allLayers, info, std::string(fisFile));
            saveAsGeoTiff(std::string(geotifFile), allLayers, fisData, latitude, longitude, realLength, realWidth, heading);    

        return SUCCESS;
    }

//FUNCTION TO EXTRACT BUFFERS FROM FIS FILE
vector<Mat> extractFisData(bool allLayers, LcmsSystemInfo info, string fisFileName)
{
    int nLayers = (allLayers) ? NUM_PAGES_ALL : NUM_PAGES_STRIPPED;
    vector<Mat> fisData(nLayers);       
    GetIntensityImage(fisFileName, &info, fisData[0]);      
    GetRangeImage(fisFileName, &info, fisData[1]);
    if(allLayers)
    {
            getLeftAndRightIntensity(fisData[2], fisData[3], &info);            
            getLeftAndRightRange(fisData[4], fisData[5], &info);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<nLayers; i++)
        flip(fisData[i], fisData[i], 0);
    return fisData;
}

//FUNCTION TO CREATE GEOTIFF GIVEN THE BUFFERS
void saveAsGeoTiff(string geoTifName, bool allLayers, vector<Mat> fisData, double lattitude, double longitude, double imageLatDist, double imageLongDist, double heading)
{
    int num_pages = (allLayers) ? NUM_PAGES_ALL : NUM_PAGES_STRIPPED;
    TIFFSetErrorHandler(NULL);
    TIFFSetWarningHandler(NULL);
    augment_libtiff_with_custom_tags();
    TIFF *tiffdata = TIFFOpen(geoTifName.c_str(), "w");
    for(int page = 0; page<num_pages; page++)
    {
            setCoreTiffTags(tiffdata, page, num_pages, fisData[page]);
            if(page==0)
            {
                    setCustomTiffTags(tiffdata, allLayers);
                    setGeoTiffTags(tiffdata, lattitude, longitude, imageLatDist, imageLongDist, heading, fisData[page]);
            }
            TIFFWriteEncodedStrip(tiffdata, 0, static_cast<void *>(fisData[page].data), fisData[page].rows*fisData[page].step[0]); 
            TIFFWriteDirectory(tiffdata);
    }
    TIFFClose(tiffdata);
}
```

C# dll call:

```
[DllImport("roadware.Algorithm.GeotiffProcessor.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern int extractFisAndCreateGeotiff(String fisFile, String infoFisFile, String tifFile, bool allLayers, double latitude, double longitude, double realX, double realY, double heading);

 private void CreateGeotifFiles(List<string> fisFilesList, string infoFisFile, List<string> tiffFilesList, List<double> geoPositions, List<double> fisRealSizes, List<double> headings)
        {
            ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
            po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2;
            Parallel.For(0, fisFilesList.Count, po, i =>
            //for (int i = 0; i < fisFilesList.Count; i++)
            {
                    extractFisAndCreateGeotiff(fisFilesList[i], infoFisFile, tiffFilesList[i], this.settings.ExtractAll, geoPositions[i * 2], geoPositions[i * 2 + 1], fisRealSizes[i * 2], fisRealSizes[i * 2 + 1], headings[i]);
            }
            );
        }
```

No error when called from normal for loop, only from Parallel.For. I am new to parallel programming and threading. Any help would be appreciated!

Exception:
[image]

Call Stack:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Few pointers:
1. there are initialization calls, which are definitely modifying global state, try doing them once
2. Sometimes c dlls are not thread safe at all, sometimes they are local thread safe. In case of parallel.for you will get same threads re-used, so you might be better off if you try explicitly one thread per image.

Also, search hint: "libtiff thread safe"